# why need to composer dump-autoload

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

i write a package manager for Laravel without need to Packagist. but every time a module added, need to run:

`composer dump-autoload`

in terminal.

how to automate load new module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options for you to setup composer's autoload behaviours.

I'd recommend using `psr-4` autoloading, for example:

```
...
"autoload": {
    // The rest of your composer autoload
    // add your namespace below
    "psr-4": [
        "Foo\\" : "app/Foo"
    ]
},
...
```

What this does is simply telling composer that you are following PSR-0/PSR-4 convention on structuring your folder/directory according to your namespace. You'll need to do `composer dump-autoload` for this to work the first time, but it'll pick new modules up automatically the next time without `dump-autoload`.

Read more on PSR guidelines here: [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) and [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

Amazing laracasts by Jeffrey Way: https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading

Comment: Thanks. i don't read about PSR-0 or PSR-4 and i must to look this. but in my app every module have a different namespace. can i put a composer.json for every module and this module loaded automatically?

Comment: When you say in different namespaces, do they at least start with the same namespace root? It'll be very odd to have modules in totally separate namespace. On related note, if you want to avoid having to call `dump-autoload` every time modules are edited/added this is the most practical way.

Comment: Every module that has it's own `composer.json` can autoload as many namespaces as it likes and needs. Pay attention to not create conflicting namespaces in two modules, because that will create very nasty to debug errors if the same class exists twice accidentially and the "wrong" version is autoloaded.